# The existence of Young subgroups of $S_n$

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, symmetric-groups

I'm currently reading a book on the representations of the symmetric group of $n$ letters $S_n$ ("The Symmetric Group" by Bruce Sagan), in which the following group is defined as groundwork in order to describe the irreducible representations of $S_n$: Let $\lambda$ be a partition of $n$ (i.e. $\lambda =(\lambda _i)_{i=1}^k$ such that $\lambda _i\geq \lambda _{i+1}$ and $\displaystyle \sum _i\lambda _i=n$.) we define de Young subgroup $S_\lambda$ of $S_n$ as$$S_\lambda :=S_{\{1,\ldots ,\lambda _1\}}\times S_{\{\lambda _1+1,\ldots ,\lambda _1+\lambda _2\}}\times \cdots \times S_{\{n-\lambda _k+1,\ldots ,n\}} \qquad... (1)$$The book asserts (without proof) that there exists a subgroup $H$ of $S_n$ which is isomorphic to $S_\lambda$ but I don't see why.

My thoughts on the question are that, in general, if $H $ and $K$ are subgroups of a group $G$ then $HK = KH$ iff $HK$ is subgroup of $G$. I guess this last result can be extended for a finite arbitrary family of subgroups of a group $G$ and, because $\{1,\ldots ,\lambda _1\}, \{\lambda_1 +1,\ldots ,\lambda _1 + \lambda_2\}, \dots, \{ n - \lambda_k + 1, \dots, \lambda_k \}$ are all disjoint thus $S_{\{1,\ldots ,\lambda _1\}}S_{\{\lambda _1+1,\ldots ,\lambda _1+\lambda _2\}}\cdots S_{\{n-\lambda _k+1,\ldots ,n\}}$ is a subgroup of $S_n$ in which the terms of the product are mutually disjoint and normal in such subgroup and thus itself is isomorphic to the direct product stated in (1)

Comment: Which book are you referring to?

Comment: Also, your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: $S_n$ naturally acts on the set {1,2,3,....,n}.  For each of those subsets in your problem, consider the subgroup that fixes everything not in the subset.  Now, take the (internal) direct product of those subgroups.

Comment: As another way of putting Aaron's comment, $H$ would be the subgroup of permutations which fix each of $\{ 1, \ldots, \lambda_1 \}$, $\{ \lambda_1 + 1, \ldots, \lambda_2 \}$, $\ldots$.

Comment: I've added Shaun's advice and taken Aaron's suggestion in the last edit and thus think I've stated the solution. Thank you all for your attention